# Based on value of the present table column, get the data from another table in sql

Tags: mysql, node.js, select, sequelize.js, case

I am trying to write a sql query to list all the users along with vendor info.
In tbl_users table, column vendor_type can have only company or agency and i am storing
the company_id or agency_id in vendor_id based on vendor_type value.

**Example 1** : In first row of the `tbl_users`, `user_id=1` and value of the `vendor_type` is `company`, So I want to get the vendor data from the `tbl_company` table WHERE `company_id(vendor_id) = 2`.

**Example 2** : Similarly In second row of the `tbl_users`, `user_id=2` and value of the `vendor_type` is `agency`, So I want to get the vendor data from the `tbl_agency` table WHERE `agency_id(vendor_id) = 8`.

```
tbl_users
+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| user_id  | username | vendor_type | vendor_id |
+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+
|        1 | Vicky RT |  company    |   2       |
|        2 | Adam Sm  |  agency     |   8       |
|        3 | Shane JK |  company    |   5       |
+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+

tbl_company
+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
| company_id | name        | contact_number| reg_date   |
+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+
|        1   | ABC Pvt Ltd | 0123456789    | 2020-10-21 |
|        2   | XYZ Pvt Ltd | 1234567890    | 2008-08-15 |
+------------+-------------+---------------+------------+

tbl_agency
+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| agency_id | name        | licence_number| logo         |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
|        8  | ABC Agency  | O3BD3OU6FG    | abc-3463.png |
|        9  | XYZ Agency  | UDBD3N5O5W    | xyz-3463.png |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
```

And I tried this below query but not getting the result.

```
SELECT user_id, username, vendor_type, vendor_id
CASE 
    WHEN vendor_type='company' THEN (SELECT company_id, name, contact_number, reg_date 
       FROM tbl_company WHERE tbl_company.company_id=tbl_users.vendor_id)
    WHEN vendor_type='agency' THEN (SELECT agency_id, name, licence_number, logo 
       FROM tbl_agency WHERE tbl_agency.agency_id=tbl_users.vendor_id)
    ELSE 'null'
END AS vendor_info
FROM `tbl_users`
```